# C++ difference between unsigned char and char with multiplication

Tags: c++, char, integer, multiplication

Why does `char` overflow when multiplied by an integer literal and `unsigned char` doesn't and it casts to `int` or `unsigned int`?

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    char MAX1=200;
    unsigned char MAX2=200;

    cout << MAX1*3 << endl;
    cout << MAX2*3 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The above code otputs:

> -168
>
> 600

Comment: Hint: Try printing `MAX1` before the multiplication.

Comment: @BaummitAugen nice, but let it be `cout << MAX1 * 1 << "\n";` --> -56 ;)

Comment: @A.S.H While we are at it, `cout << +MAX1 << "\n";` works too and looks even cooler. ;)

Comment: @BaummitAugen lol, same result, so long as `MAX1` was converted to `int` ;)

Comment: MAX1 * 3 gets promoted to signed integer.  MAX2 * 3 gets promoted to unsigned integer.

Comment: I don't think that's the case rcgldr. They're both integers. https://ideone.com/N6L7UO

Comment: Ohh yes! I see now clearly. Both are casted to int, it's just that MAX1 had overflowed, then casted to int, then multiplied. Thanks to @BaummitAugen

Comment: @ZdravkoDonev: It's fine to answer your own question ... and that was an answer.

Comment: @ZdravkoDonev You're welcome. I expanded my comment to a full answer below to include the details of what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is not in the multiplication as you assumed, but in the assignment at the beginning. The important thing to note here is that it's implementation defined whether `char` is signed or unsigned.

On your platform, `char` is apparently signed and thus cannot represent `200`. That leaves us with a variable `MAX1` which has an implementation defined value, in our case `-56`. (Due to 2s complement on common platforms.)

Then, the multiplication part is the same for both variables: The operands get promoted to `int` because the conversion rank of (`unsigned`) `char` is less than the conversion rank of `int` and we end up with the equivalent of

```
cout << int(-56) * 3 << endl;
cout << int(200) * 3 << endl;
```

which prints

> -168
>   600

as one would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh yes! I see now clearly. Both are casted to `int`, it's just that `MAX1` had overflowed, then casted to `int`, then multiplied. Thanks to @BaummitAugen

Comment: Note that Baum has now [posted an expanded answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40962144/4099593)